# cassandra primary key where cause limitation

Tags: cassandra, primary-key, clustering-key

I want to use cassandra as a DB to store messages, when in my model messages are aggregate by channel.
the 3 main important field of message:

1. channel_id
2. created_by
3. message_id (unique)

The main read/fetch API is get messages by channel sorted by `created_by`.
Plus, I have a low scale messages update by `channel_id` + `message_id`.

So my question is regarding the primary_key definition.
If I will define it `(channel_id,created_by)`
will I be able to do an `UPDATE` with `WHERE` cLause like `channel_id=X and message_id=XX`, even if `message_id` is not in the primary key (I do give the query the partition key)?

And if not,
if I will define the primary key like this `(channel_id,created_by, message_id)`
will I be able to do the read with where cause with only 1 clustering column `(channel_id,created_by)`
and do the update using the where cause `channel_id` + `message_id`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> define it `(channel_id,created_by)` will I be able to do an `UPDATE` with `WHERE` cLause like `channel_id=X` and `message_id=XX`

No.  All primary key components are required for a write operation in Cassandra.  First you will have to provide `created_by`. `message_id` is not part of the key, so that will have to be removed.

> And if not, if I will define the primary key like this `(channel_id,created_by, message_id)` will I be able to do the read with `WHERE` cause with only 1 clustering column `(channel_id,created_by)`

Yes, this will work:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE channel_id='1' AND created_by='Aaron';
```

This ^ works, because you have provided the first two primary key components, without skipping any.  Cassandra can easily find the node containing the partition for `channel_id`, and scan down to the row starting with `created_by`.

> and do the update using the WHERE cause `channel_id` + `message_id`?

No.  Again, you would need to provide `created_by` for the write to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

The primary key selection decision is one of the most important part in Cassandra data modeling. You need to understand the table. I am not sure if I can help you with the above-provided information by you. But I will still give it a try.

Your requirement:

1. Sort by created_by.
2. Update with channel_id + message_id

Try having channel_id + message_id as the partition key and created_by as clustering key. Message_id in the primary key will also help in ensuring uniqueness.

Recently I found DS220 course on Data modeling on https://academy.datastax.com/. This is awesome.